# Pasar una cadena de texto que representa una lista a una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una variable llamada `y` que tiene el valor `"[a,b,c]"` ( es `str` )
y quiero pasarla a una lista que se llame `x`.

¿Como haría eso? Si utilizo el método `list(y)` no funciona porque devuelve esto:

```
['[', "'", 'a', "'", ',', "'", 'b', "'", ',', "'", 'c', "'", ']']
```

y yo quiero que sea:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si aplicas `list` sobre una cadena (que es lo que es `y`, aunque se parezca a la representación de una lista), obtienes una lista en las que los items son los caracteres de esa cadena.

Para el ejemplo concreto que ofreces, siempre que los "items" estén separados solo por una coma y que no existan anidamientos ni se use la coma dentro de un item, puedes hacer algo como:

```
y  = "[a,b,c]"
x = y[1: -1].split(",")
```

Simplemente aplicamos un slicing para quedarnos con lo que hay dentro de los corchetes y usamos `str.split` para partir la cadena (`"a,b,c"` en este caso) usando la coma.

Si la cadena fuera la representación válida de una lista Python (retorno de `repr(lista)`), lo suyo sería usar `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

y  = "['a', 'b', 'c']"
x = ast.literal_eval(y)
```

Por desgracia en este caso no lo es, se podría recurrir a `ast.parser` con algo de trabajo, si necesitáramos algo más flexible que la primera opción.

Comment: Gracias esa es la solucion que buscaba PD: casi siempre te veo en las preguntas de python